# Firefox compatible input filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm trying to prevent most special characters (with the exception of "_" and "-") from working on a text input field.

I started with doing a regex filter by pattern(didnt work), then by dynamic js, later to find out that it wouldn't work on firefox, I coudldn't use the dashes, underscores, backspace, delete, or arrow keys even though it showed I could on https://regexr.com/

I found another solution that actually prevented the keypress by using the ascii tables, sounded great as well but now I still can't use underscores or dashes though the my logic seems fine and the keys aren't logged.

```
<input id="directory" type="text">

$("#directory").keypress(function(e){
var keyCode = e.which;

/*
48-57 - (0-9)Numbers 65-90 - (A-Z) 97-122 - (a-z) 8 - (backspace)
*/
if (
   !(
     (keyCode == 8 )
     ||(keyCode == 45)
     ||(keyCode == 95)
     ||(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)
     ||(keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)
     ||(keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122)
   )
 ){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#directory").val('')
 console.log(keyCode);
  toastr.error("Your search string contains illegal characters.  Please use, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, or _", "Error", {timeOut: 10000, preventDuplicates:true, positionClass : "toast-top-center"}); 
  }
});
```

edit: the inverse of this didn't work either of course

```
 if (
   (
     (keyCode >= 0 && keyCode <= 7)
     ||(keyCode >= 9 && keyCode <= 44)
     ||(keyCode >= 46 && keyCode <= 47)
     ||(keyCode >= 58 && keyCode <= 64)
     ||(keyCode >= 91 && keyCode <= 94)
     ||(keyCode == 96)
     ||(keyCode >= 123 && keyCode <= 127)
   )
){
```

I'm not sure why, but 45 and 95 still wont let me enter underscores or dashes, can anyone help me, the solution I want is a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _ input?

Comment: Have you thought about copy/paste, drag-'n-drop, ... ?

Comment: on input will handle paste and such

Comment: I'm not worried about anything being injected, I'm just trying to prevent normal users from inserting characters I cant process.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not depend on `keydown`, as it will not fire when you paste content with the context menu (for example). To get an event fired for any change applied by the user, use the `input` event.

The downside of that event is that it cannot be cancelled. But it is not too difficult to undo the (part of the) change that has invalid characters in it.

Here is how it could work:

```js
$('#directory').on('input', function (e) {
    var i = $(this).val().search(/[^\w-]/);
    if (i < 0) return; // All OK
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\w-]/g, ''));
    this.setSelectionRange(i, i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="directory" type="text">
```

My opinion is that such blocking of characters is actually user-unfriendly: people might for a moment think their keyboard is malfunctioning. It is probably better to allow the characters to be typed, but to give a visual indication that the input is not valid, for example with a red border and an accompanying message.

Comment: this doesnt seem to allow _ or -

Comment: @BrendanJackson, Strange, I can type them. Did you try the snippet?

Comment: yeah, maybe there is something I am missing though, I'm testing on a live site not js fiddle or anything.

Comment: No, I mean, did you press the "run code snippet" in my answer? Of course, on a site there may be other code that is interfering... Make sure to implement it with removal of other code that may also treat (keyboard) events, and/or cancel them.

Comment: It works on your snippet, that said, its not working on my site.

Comment: That means that other code is somehow blocking input. Without seeing your site's code, I cannot really tell which part of your code is interfering. If you can produce a fiddle that reproduces the problem I could have a look at it.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

It was a logic inversion issue ... all of the || allowed for characters you didn't want to "slip through".  I removed the !() part and just returned from the event handler when an allowed key was typed:

```js
var $output = $("#output")

$("#directory").keypress(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.charCode;

  /*
  48-57 - (0-9)Numbers 65-90 - (A-Z) 97-122 - (a-z) 8 - (backspace)
  */
 
    if (
      (keyCode == 8) ||
      (keyCode == 45) ||
      (keyCode == 95) ||
      (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||
      (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) ||
      (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122)
    ) return
    
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#directory").val('')
    console.log(keyCode);
    $output.text("Your search string contains illegal characters.  Please use, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, or _");
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="directory" type="text">

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: I'm able to enter in things like '%%%%%' and '*****' on chrome, which fails what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Still has the issue.

Comment: Yeah ... I fixed it.